# How to add tomcat connection pool properties to custom DataSource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I want to have multiple `DataSource` in my application. Therefore cannot rely on the datasource autoconfiguration of Spring and have to create my own, like this:

```
        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.custom")
        public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

spring.datasource.custom.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename
spring.datasource.custom.username=root
spring.datasource.custom.password=rootpw
spring.datasource.custom.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#the important part:
spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Problem: the `.tomcat.*` properties are not automatically picked up.

Question: how can I get them into the `DataSource`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create multiple Datasource beans with one of them being `@Primary` and you can set tomcat connection pool properties like this

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.validation-query}")
private String validationQuery;

@Value("${spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.test-on-borrow}")
private boolean onBorrow;

    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    ds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
    ds.setTestOnBorrow(onBorrow);
```

Instead of `return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();` you need to return the datasource u created above

Comment: Ok but can't I rely just on the configured `spring.datasource.custom.tomcat=` properties? Eg what if I added the connection pool properties like `spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.max-active=`? For the default datasource spring would pick up those tomcat properties automatically. How can I now assign those to my custom datasource? I mean, how does spring autoconfigure add those tomcat properties to the ds when relying on a single datasource during autoconfig?

Comment: you have autowire these properties(using `@Value`) in the bean where you are creating your datasources and use those. Springboot will pick the values only when you are using the default datasource and the properties match exactly as specified by spring. Spring will not pick if you create a property like spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.max-active

Comment: Ok, do you know where I can find the spring auto configuration that reads out the `.tomcat*` properties during a normal autoconfig startup? So maybe I could just inherit or copypaste the code they use.

Comment: check `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Spring seems to be setting the tomcat properties by *reflection*, inside `AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues()`. So probably indeed the only chance is to inject the parameters by `@Value' and set them explicit on the tomcat `DataSource`...

Answer (score 3):

With the following lines in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.custom.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename
spring.datasource.custom.username=root
spring.datasource.custom.password=rootpw
spring.datasource.custom.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.custom.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

#the important part:
spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.custom.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Your configuration beans should look like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.custom")
public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
     return new DataSourceProperties;
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.custom.tomcat")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
     return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

My current Spring Boot version is 1.5.18

Answer (score 1):

I got this working very simply by looking how spring boot does it through the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat class.

Example:

```
@Bean
@Primary // or @Qualifier("foobar")
@ConfigurationProperties("foobar.datasource")
DataSourceProperties foobarDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary // or @Qualifier("foobar")
@ConfigurationProperties("foobar.datasource.tomcat")
public org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource foobarDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(properties, org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class);
    DatabaseDriver databaseDriver = DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(properties.determineUrl());
    String validationQuery = databaseDriver.getValidationQuery();
    if (validationQuery != null) {
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
    }
    return dataSource;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T createDataSource(/*@Qualifier("foobar")*/ DataSourceProperties properties, Class<? extends DataSource> type) {
    return (T) properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(type).build();
}
```

And this properties will get picked up:

```
foobar.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=false
foobar.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
foobar.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval=5000
foobar.datasource.tomcat.<whateve other props tomcat's pool accepts>=xxx
```